# jquery chained selects with multiple parents - last select is always 'disabled'

Tags: jquery, chained-select

I am trying to implement a chained select dependent on 2 parent selects, but the child select always remains disabled, with no options loading. As far as I can tell, the first-parent\second-parent format is correct in my data, but yet the child select won't fire.

My setup is as follows:

- 1st parent select: years (year-2016, year-2015, year-2014...)
- 2nd parent select: media types (article, gallery, video)

If "year-2015" and "article" are selected, then the child select should display options with the class "year-2015\article".

Scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.js"></script>
<script>$("#item").chained("#year, #mediatypes");</script>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle with the generated HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/lukenjohnson/wzcfz8e5/3/)

My code seems to be consistent with [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/VwuvY/1/) -- but I can't identify why my child select won't fire. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem shortly after taking the time to post this...

I had put the classes in the wrong order. My child select needed classes formatted as 'year-2015\article', not 'article\year-2015'. Simple error, but I'm "answering" my question in case someone else makes the same mistake.

Comment: Post the original code in the question, not just the fiddle. And show the corrected code here in the answer.